# TensorFlow's Estimator can only get N-1 batches from tf.train.limit_epochs

Tags: tensorflow

Hi this is a follow up question from [TensorFlow's Estimator froze with low CPU usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42124976/tensorflows-estimator-froze-with-low-cpu-usage).

The following code works fine if the `evaluate` steps is `1`, but if it is empty or `2`, which should be the correct number of steps because there are four rows in `feature_a` and `feature_b` and the batch_size is 2, it will throw an `OutOfRange` Error. I suppose the Estimator should catch this OutOfRange and use it to stop the evaluation but it does not and the program exits.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.layers.python.layers.optimizers import optimize_loss
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import model_fn
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.estimator import Estimator
from tensorflow.python import debug as tf_debug
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops


def main(_):
    hooks = [tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugHook()]

    def func(features, targets, mode, params):
        idx = tf.concat([features['a'], features['b']], axis=1)

        embedding = tf.get_variable("embed", [10, 20], dtype=tf.float32)

        pred = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, idx))

        train_op = optimize_loss(loss=pred,
                                 global_step=tf.train.get_global_step(),
                                 learning_rate=0.001,
                                 optimizer='Adam',
                                 variables=tf.trainable_variables(),
                                 name="training_loss_optimizer")

        eval_metric_dict = dict()
        eval_metric_dict['metric'] = pred

        return model_fn.ModelFnOps(mode=mode,
                                   predictions=pred,
                                   loss=pred,
                                   train_op=train_op,
                                   eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_dict)

    model = Estimator(func, params={})

    model.fit(
        input_fn=lambda: (
            {'a': ops.convert_to_tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]), 'b': ops.convert_to_tensor([[2, 3, 4, 3, 5]])},
            None), max_steps=10)

    testing_data_a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
    testing_data_b = [[2, 3, 4, 3, 5], [2, 3, 4, 3, 5], [2, 3, 4, 3, 5], [2, 3, 4, 3, 5]]

    def test_input_fn():
        feature_a = tf.train.limit_epochs(testing_data_a, num_epochs=1)
        feature_b = tf.train.limit_epochs(testing_data_b, num_epochs=1)

        feature_a_producer = tf.train.batch([feature_a], batch_size=2, enqueue_many=True, allow_smaller_final_batch=True)
        feature_b_producer = tf.train.batch([feature_b], batch_size=2, enqueue_many=True, allow_smaller_final_batch=True)

        return {'a': feature_a_producer, 'b': feature_b_producer}, None

    for i in range(10):
        # This does not work
        print(model.evaluate(input_fn=test_input_fn))
        # This does not work
        # print(model.evaluate(input_fn=test_input_fn, steps=2))
        # This do work
        # print(model.evaluate(input_fn=test_input_fn, steps=1))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    tf.app.run()
```

The error stack looks like this

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory: /tmp/tmpo89sneqt
2017-02-08 21:51:17.428803: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Out of range: FIFOQueue '_0_batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 2, current size 0)
     [[Node: batch = QueueDequeueUpToV2[component_types=[DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](batch/fifo_queue, batch/n)]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1022, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1004, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: FIFOQueue '_0_batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 2, current size 0)
     [[Node: batch = QueueDequeueUpToV2[component_types=[DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](batch/fifo_queue, batch/n)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/training/python/training/evaluation.py", line 442, in evaluate_once
    session.run(eval_ops, feed_dict)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 469, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 793, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 751, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 898, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 751, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1035, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: FIFOQueue '_0_batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 2, current size 0)
     [[Node: batch = QueueDequeueUpToV2[component_types=[DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](batch/fifo_queue, batch/n)]]

Caused by op 'batch', defined at:
  File "/data/bshi/ProjC/estimator_test.py", line 59, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/data/bshi/ProjC/estimator_test.py", line 55, in main
    print(model.evaluate(input_fn=test_input_fn))
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 281, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 507, in evaluate
    log_progress=log_progress)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 798, in _evaluate_model
    features, labels = input_fn()
  File "/data/bshi/ProjC/estimator_test.py", line 49, in test_input_fn
    feature_a_producer = tf.train.batch([feature_a], batch_size=2, enqueue_many=True, allow_smaller_final_batch=True)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 917, in batch
    name=name)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 710, in _batch
    dequeued = queue.dequeue_up_to(batch_size, name=name)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py", line 510, in dequeue_up_to
    self._queue_ref, n=n, component_types=self._dtypes, name=name)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 1402, in _queue_dequeue_up_to_v2
    timeout_ms=timeout_ms, name=name)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2402, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1264, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_0_batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 2, current size 0)
     [[Node: batch = QueueDequeueUpToV2[component_types=[DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](batch/fifo_queue, batch/n)]]


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1022, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1004, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: FIFOQueue '_0_batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 2, current size 0)
     [[Node: batch = QueueDequeueUpToV2[component_types=[DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](batch/fifo_queue, batch/n)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/bshi/ProjC/estimator_test.py", line 59, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/data/bshi/ProjC/estimator_test.py", line 55, in main
    print(model.evaluate(input_fn=test_input_fn))
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 281, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 507, in evaluate
    log_progress=log_progress)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 825, in _evaluate_model
    config=config_pb2.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True))
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/training/python/training/evaluation.py", line 442, in evaluate_once
    session.run(eval_ops, feed_dict)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 485, in __exit__
    self._close_internal(exception_type)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 515, in _close_internal
    h.end(self._coordinated_creator.tf_sess)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 663, in end
    feed_dict=self._final_ops_feed_dict)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1035, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: FIFOQueue '_0_batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 2, current size 0)
     [[Node: batch = QueueDequeueUpToV2[component_types=[DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](batch/fifo_queue, batch/n)]]

Caused by op 'batch', defined at:
  File "/data/bshi/ProjC/estimator_test.py", line 59, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/data/bshi/ProjC/estimator_test.py", line 55, in main
    print(model.evaluate(input_fn=test_input_fn))
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 281, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 507, in evaluate
    log_progress=log_progress)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 798, in _evaluate_model
    features, labels = input_fn()
  File "/data/bshi/ProjC/estimator_test.py", line 49, in test_input_fn
    feature_a_producer = tf.train.batch([feature_a], batch_size=2, enqueue_many=True, allow_smaller_final_batch=True)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 917, in batch
    name=name)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 710, in _batch
    dequeued = queue.dequeue_up_to(batch_size, name=name)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py", line 510, in dequeue_up_to
    self._queue_ref, n=n, component_types=self._dtypes, name=name)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 1402, in _queue_dequeue_up_to_v2
    timeout_ms=timeout_ms, name=name)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2402, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/data/bshi/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1264, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_0_batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 2, current size 0)
     [[Node: batch = QueueDequeueUpToV2[component_types=[DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](batch/fifo_queue, batch/n)]]


Process finished with exit code 1
```